# Download files with Android Webview

Tags: java, php, android, webview

I am making an Android app that uses a WebView to access to a webpage. To handle downloads I am using AsyncTask in method onDownloadStart of WebView's DownloadListener. However files downloaded are blank (although the filename and extension are correct). My Java code is this:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... url) {  
    try {
        URL url = new URL(url[0]);    

        //Creating directory if not exists

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);        
        connection.connect();

        //Obtaining filename

        File outputFile = new File(directory, filename);
        InputStream input   = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

        byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        int count = 0;
        Log.e(null, "input.read(data) = "+input.read(data), null);
        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }              
        connection.disconnect();
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

log.e line gives -1 value for input.read(data).
PHP code of download page is this (works in all platforms). Files are stored in non-public directories of my HTML server.

```
<?php
$guid = $_GET['id'];
$file = get_file($guid);

if (isset($file['path'])) { 
    $mime = $file['MIMEType'];
    if (!$mime) {
        $mime = "application/octet-stream";
    }

    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Content-type: $mime");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$file['filename']}\"");
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file['path']);
    exit();

}
?>
```

I've noticed that if I write some text after "?>" of PHP file, this text is written in the file downloaded.

Comment: What's your question / exact problem?

Comment: My problem is that files I download with my app are completely blank, but if I write something after PHP code, it will be written on my file. I think problem is in input because when I do log of this, value returned is -1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you are using [`ob_clean()`](https://www.php.net/ob_clean), which will just erase the output buffer. Your subsequent call to `flush()` therefore doesn't return anything, because the output buffer has been flushed beforehand.

Instead of `ob_clean()` and `flush()`, use [`ob_end_flush()`](https://www.php.net/ob_end_flush). This will stop output buffering and it will send all the output it withheld.

> ob_end_flush — Flush (send) the output buffer and turn off output buffering

If you want to stop output buffering *without* outputting whatever is saved, you can use [`ob_end_clean()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php). Anything after this command will be output again, but anything between `ob_start()` and `ob_end_clean()` will be "swallowed."

> ob_end_clean — Clean (erase) the output buffer and turn off output buffering

What are the benefits of output buffering in the first place? If you are doing `ob_start()` and then using `flush()` on everything you might as well output everything directly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have read about your solution and I think is better than mine, so I have replaced. However I can't get files yet. I tried to add _header("Content-Length: ".$file['size'])_ in PHP file and _int length = connection.getContentLength();_ in Java file and length value is 0. It might be problem of BufferedInputStream?

Comment: @AngelF. Best is to start small. I would recommend forgetting about output buffers and setting headers and just read the file without much around it. Then you can gradually add parameters, such as the content's length.

Comment: I'm going to do it. Thanks again.